# I have a master table and a result from sql query.How do i join these the master table and a result set to get the missing ID's

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1 :"Material"

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
```

query:

```
SELECT ID FROM 
(Select * From
 (Select Distinct(ID)  from tablex Union All 
Select Distinct(ID) from tabley Union All 
Select Distinct(ID) from tablez Union All )
```

o/p from above query is 1,2 &3

finale output reqd:
4
5

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: And an explanation of the logic you want implemented.

Comment: Please dont put your question in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ids in the master but not in the child tables, you can use `not exists`:

```
select m.*
from master m
where not exists (select 1 from child1 c1 where c1.id = m.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from child2 c2 where c2.id = m.id);
```